# ionic build with "SplashScreen.java uses or overrides a deprecated API." error

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I managed to build a `apk` file successfully using ionic after running the command `ionic build android`. However, this `apk` file could not be installed successfully onto my Android phone.

During the built process, I encountered the following warnings:

```
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaNote:
> Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile
> with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

:compileDebugJavaNote:
> C:\Users\own\Dropbox\Workplace\xampp568\htdocs\stkview\stkApp\platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\splashscreen\SplashScreen.java
> uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
> -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Could this be the cause? How do I remove these warnings?

Comment: May I ask what is wrong with the question? Why the negative vote?

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered this error before. What happened on my PC was that the system variable `JAVA_HOME` was not defined. After defining `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_67`, the warning disappeared and the installation was done successfully. Not sure if it works on your machine. Hopefully, it helps.

Comment: Same problem here on linux (ubuntu 15.10, java-8-oracle, ionic 1.7.14), but this solution didn't work for me.

Comment: I am facing same issue. JAVA_HOME is properly set "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle". Any guess?